# jQuery Get data-attribute of all checkbox into a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes that looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="pcb" value="1" data-id="99">
<input type="checkbox" class="pcb" value="2" data-id="98">
<input type="checkbox" class="pcb" value="3" data-id="97">
```

And originally I only needed the value inside the value attribute of the checked checkbox. I use this javascript/jquery code to do that:

```
var receiptNos = $("#result input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Using this code gives me: `receiptNos = '1,2,3'`
Now I need to have another string variable that will hold the content of data-id of all checked checkboxes: `receiptNos2 = '99,98,97'`

I tried using:

```
var receiptNos2 = $("#result input:checkbox:checked").attr('data-id').map(function () {
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead `return $(this).val();` you can use `return $(this).data('id');`

```
var receiptNos2 = $("#result input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
    return $(this).data('id')
}).get();
```

Comment: Nice that works. Thanks bud. I will mark this as the answer after 10mins (answered too quick)